# Convert Name/Value Pair XML to Elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file consisting of Name/Value pairs that I need in a format using xslt 1 where each "Name" is an element name with the Value in the contents. Here is an example:

Input:

```
<Root>
  <Entities>
    <Entity EntityName="Client">
      <Data Name="ADDR_City">Anytown</Data>
      <Data Name="ADDR_State">SC</Data>
      <Data Name="ADDR_Zip">23904</Data>
    </Entity>
  </Entities>
</Root>
```

Output:

```
<Root>
  <Entities>
    <Client>
      <ADDR_City>Anytown</ADDR_City>
      <ADDR_State>SC</ADDR_State>
      <ADDR_Zip>23904</ADDR_Zip>
    </Client>
  </Entities>
</Root>
```

The EntityName of Client is not necessarily the only way this would work...I'm mainly concerned with getting the Data Name="... fields into the correct format. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : Apologies - I missed the `Entity` name. Updated assuming the cardinality is many `<Entity> per <Entities>`. I guess I also need to point out that this will fail if the attributes EntityName or Name have invalid element characters (e.g. space), or if the attributes are missing entirely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root>
      <xsl:for-each select="Entities">
        <Entities>
          <xsl:for-each select="Entity">
            <xsl:element name="{@EntityName}">
              <xsl:for-each select="Data">
                <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Entities>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That works except I have multiple Entity tags and this only outputs the first one that has a Data element under it (several are blank). How can I change it to output all of the <Entity>s?

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data">
   <xsl:element Name="{@Name}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Lowercase 'n': `<xsl:element name="{@Name}">`