# Issue in converting name/value xml to element xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to convert a name/value xml to element xml using xsl. I tried every method which I could find. I refered this post, [Convert Name/Value Pair XML to Elements using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996928/convert-name-value-pair-xml-to-elements-using-xslt/44810213?noredirect=1#comment76601118_44810213) and made the changes, but my resultant xml doesn't show the key values.

Below are my code files:

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<METSM xmlns="metsmng" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<Case id="MTMzo29276" ns2:href="https://metsm.com/api/case/MTMzo29276">
    <Column name="BU">SU</Column>
    <Column name="Summary">Hardware failure</Column>
    <Column name="Project">Servers</Column>
    <Column name="Priority">High</Column>
    <Column name="Status">Working</Column>
    <Column name="Open-Date">01/23/2017 23:11:16</Column>
</Case>
<Case id="MTMzo29739" ns2:href="https://metsm.com/api/case/MTMzo29739">
    <Column name="BU">AICM</Column>
    <Column name="Summary">Create a new profile</Column>
    <Column name="Project">Datacentre</Column>
    <Column name="Priority">Low</Column>
    <Column name="Status">Open</Column>
    <Column name="Open-Date">10/04/2010 00:00:00</Column>
</Case>
</METSM>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/METSM">
<METSM>
   <xsl:for-each select="Case">
   <Case>
      <xsl:element name="{@id}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:for-each select="Column">
         <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </Case>
</xsl:for-each>
</METSM>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output required:

```
<METSM>
<Case>
  <id> MTMzo29276 </id>
  <BU> SU </BU>
  <Summary> Hardware failure </Summary>
  ....
</Case>
<Case>
 ....
</Case>
</METSM>
```

What I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    SU
    Hardware failed
    Servers
    High
    Working
    01/23/2017 23:11:16


    AICM
    Create a new profile
    Datacentre
    Low
    Open
    10/04/2010 00:00:00
```

I am not able to figure out the issue. How do I get the key names in my result xml file. Any help will be highly grateful. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: using below python code to generate the output xml file:

```
 from lxml import etree
 data = open(r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\input-xsl.xsl')
 xslt_content = data.read()
 xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
 dom = etree.parse(r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\input-xml.xml')
 transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
 result = transform(dom)
 print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your XML is in the default namespace `metsmng`. Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use `xpath-default-namespace`...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xpath-default-namespace="metsmng">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/METSM">
    <METSM>
      <xsl:for-each select="Case">
        <Case>
          <id><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></id>
          <xsl:for-each select="Column">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Case>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </METSM>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also notice that I fixed your `id` element output.

**Output**

```
<METSM>
   <Case>
      <id>MTMzo29276</id>
      <BU>SU</BU>
      <Summary>Hardware failure</Summary>
      <Project>Servers</Project>
      <Priority>High</Priority>
      <Status>Working</Status>
      <Open-Date>01/23/2017 23:11:16</Open-Date>
   </Case>
   <Case>
      <id>MTMzo29739</id>
      <BU>AICM</BU>
      <Summary>Create a new profile</Summary>
      <Project>Datacentre</Project>
      <Priority>Low</Priority>
      <Status>Open</Status>
      <Open-Date>10/04/2010 00:00:00</Open-Date>
   </Case>
</METSM>
```

---

You mentioned in the comments you are using lxml. If so, XSLT 2.0 is not supported; you'll need to use XSLT 1.0. What you'll need to do is bind the namespace to a prefix and use that prefix in your XPath's...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:m="metsmng" exclude-result-prefixes="m">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/m:METSM">
    <METSM>
      <xsl:for-each select="m:Case">
        <Case>
          <id><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></id>
          <xsl:for-each select="m:Column">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Case>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </METSM>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But I am still not getting the tags in my output xml file.

I am running the below code in python for generating my output xml file:

    from lxml import etree
    data = open(r'C:\Users\anubmand\Desktop\input-xsl.xsl')
    xslt_content = data.read()
    xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
    dom = etree.parse(r'C:\Users\anubmand\Desktop\input-xml.xml')
    transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
    result = transform(dom)
    print(result)

Comment: @starFire - Um yeah...lxml doesn't support XSLT 2.0. I'll modify my answer.